# Recover a set of K bounded positive integers from their first K moments

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose there are K unique integers $\{r_1, r_2, \dots, r_K\}$, a subset of $1, 2, \dots, N$.  I don't know the integers, but I know K, and their first K moments $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_K$ (sums of their powers, for integer powers from 1 to $K$).  Can I get the integers back?

This looks like the Hamburger moment problem for a discrete measure, but I don't see how to get the actual integers back.  I can see that this is tied to the Hankel matrix of moments $H_{ij} = \mu_{i+j-1}$, since existence and uniqueness of the problem depends on whether that matrix is positive definite.  However, I don't see how to use the matrix to *solve* for the integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you know $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_K$ then you can use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) to recover the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_i(r_1,\dots,r_K)$, and then the $r_j$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$ \sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^{K-i}e_{K-i}(r_1,\dots,r_K)x^i $$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!! :-D  The Wikipedia article you cited suggests a recursive formula for the coefficients in terms of the moments.  I can use a standard math library to get the eigenvalues from there (I need to solve the problem in practice; it's not just theoretical for me).  The only trickiness from there is relaxing the floating-point results to integers.  That's more my area of expertise but I would still appreciate tips if you have them :) .  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, what's a good book for learning these sorts of things?  Just curious :)

Comment: I don't really have a good book suggestion because I'm not an expert on the subject, but maybe take a look at the references in the Wikipedia page.